# Spilt one column into more using space

Tags: r

I have this dataframe.

```
dtext <- data.frame(text = c("John Marl","Anna Choi Lo","Erl Con"))
```

I would like to split it into more than one column using as separation the space between the words and I tried this.
data.frame(do.call('rbind', strsplit(as.character(dtext$text),' ',fixed=TRUE)))
However this is the output:

> ```
>  X1   X2   X3
> John Marl John
> Anna Choi   Lo
> Erl  Con  Erl
> ```

Here is the expected output

> ```
>  X1   X2   X3
> John Marl 
> Anna Choi   Lo
> Erl  Con
> ```
>
> How can I fix it?

Comment: `splitstackshape::cSplit(dtext, "text", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with **tidyr**

```r
library(tidyr)
dtext <- data.frame(text = c("John Marl","Anna Choi Lo","Erl Con"))
dtext <- dtext %>% separate(text, c('A', 'B', 'C'), fill = 'right')
dtext[is.na(dtext)] <- ''
dtext
#>      A    B  C
#> 1 John Marl   
#> 2 Anna Choi Lo
#> 3  Erl  Con
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I have added *fill = 'right'* as proposed by G.Grothendiek. See also [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html)

Comment: @G. Grothendiek Thank you for the hint. I have made the change.